# Change button color and HREF depending on another column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using Datatables with X-editable and have some bootstrap buttons in a table. Basically if the user updates the editable 'Status' column to 'Resolved' I want the button in the 'Validated' column to turn green. If the status is switched back to any other status it should turn back to red. This is working perfectly in this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/n74zo0ms/7/

However I need the ability to also change the link when the button changes and the link have PHP variables. Something like this:

```
href="./validate_cluster.php?id='.urlencode($tab).'&cluster='.urlencode($row2['CLUSTER_NAME']).'"
```

So depending on the status, the user will be presented with a different link they can click on.

How can I accomplish this?

**Update:**

Here is some more code. Basically when the user loads the page I query the database and display the button based on a value. But if the status is changed I need to be able to change the link as well.

PHP:

```
echo'<td class="validated">';
if ( $row['DISPLAY_TYPE'] == '1') {
    echo '<a href=".validate_cluster.php?id='.urlencode($tab).'&cluster='.urlencode($row2['CLUSTER_NAME']).'" class="btn-switch btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="fa-switch fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> Not Validated</a>';
    } elseif ( $row['DISPLAY_TYPE'] == '0')  {
    echo '<a href=".validate_with_errors.php?id='.urlencode($tab).'&cluster='.urlencode($row2['CLUSTER_NAME']).'&numerrors='.urlencode($row2['ERRORS']).'" class="btn-switch btn-sm btn-danger" ><i class="fa-switch fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Not Validated</a>';
    } 
echo'</td>';
```

Thanks.

Comment: What changes do you want to do to the link? You might not have to replace the full contents of 'cell' after every change. You could simple change the values that differs, then strip out the href-attribute, and update it depending on what you wish to do. I'm guessing the id and cluster attributes of the link always stays the same?

Comment: You could always just use AJAX to post the php file, then get the response and change the hef using JQuery or such.

Comment: @DanielSetréus The ID and the cluster attributes are going to be different depending on the link.

Comment: @solar411 Changed into what, and were are these new values? Is any request being made when status is changed (is it saved in some way) ? If so I'd suggest that the request returns the new id and cluster values. After that the values of the link could be updated with jQuery. Just like bug said.